# Python 2.7 error: max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
    x = {1:2, 3:6, 5:4}
    max(x, key=lambda i: x[i])
```

Python 2.7 error:

```
    max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

Python also throws similar error message when I use min(). How can I solve this problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: Seems to work fine [here](https://eval.in/441867).

Comment: You may have overwritten the built-in `min/max` functions with ones of your own. What is the output of `print(repr(max))` (it would normally be `<built-in function max>`)? Also: are you absolutely sure you are using python-2.7? The `key` argument was introduced in python-2.5.

Comment: The output of `print(repr(max))` is `max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
    
    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.` I am pretty sure I am using python 2.7. I checked the interpreter settings in Pycharm (what I am using) and it does show Python 2.7.

Comment: @user3451228. It's not obvious why pycharm would show that output. It's clearly not the normal `repr` of the built-in `max` (or any other function, for that matter). What does `print(type(max))` show?

Comment: The output is `<type 'function'>`

Comment: @user3451228. This must be some kind of pycharm bug, because the output seems totally contradictory. Let's try one last thing: what does `print(max.__module__, max.__class__)` show?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help these days :) I think I finally figure out what the problem is... I imported a library "cvxopt" which overwrites the max() function. I completely forgot about the "cvxopt" thing... Thanks so much again for your answer! btw the output is 
     `max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
    
    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.

('cvxopt', <type 'function'>)`